# Shell: Cyrillic vs select/case vs alignment

Tags: shell, cyrillic

Let's say I have a simple shell script with select/case structure and with some Cyrillic options (#2 & #4) -- like this:

```
PS3='Please, your choice? '
options=( \
    $'test test test' \
    $'тест тест' \
    $'test 2 test 2 test 2' \
    $'тест 2 тест тест' \
    $'test 3 test 3 test 3 test 3' \
    $'A AAA' \
    $'BBB B' \
    $'CC CC' \
    $'DDDDD' \
    $'Quit' \
    )
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
```

Then, if I run it, it aligns options weirdly -- like this:

```
~/Desktop> sh test.sh
1) test test test                  6) A AAA
2) тест тест               7) BBB B
3) test 2 test 2 test 2            8) CC CC
4) тест 2 тест тест        9) DDDDD
5) test 3 test 3 test 3 test 3    10) Quit
Please, your choice? ^C
```

However, if I get rid of Russian text in the script:

```
PS3='Please, your choice? '
options=( \
    $'test test test' \
    $'test test' \
    $'test 2 test 2 test 2' \
    $'test 2 test test' \
    $'test 3 test 3 test 3 test 3' \
    $'A AAA' \
    $'BBB B' \
    $'CC CC' \
    $'DDDDD' \
    $'Quit' \
    )
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
```

Everything will align nicely:

```
~/Desktop> sh test.sh
1) test test test                 6) A AAA
2) test test                      7) BBB B
3) test 2 test 2 test 2           8) CC CC
4) test 2 test test               9) DDDDD
5) test 3 test 3 test 3 test 3   10) Quit
Please, your choice? ^C
```

So, my question would be if it's possible to fix it somehow?

Just in case, here are my settings:

```
~/Desktop> echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
~/Desktop> echo $LC_AL
en_US.UTF-8
~/Desktop> echo $TERM
xterm-256color
```

Comment: Possibly a version issue; I can reproduce your alignment in 4.1, but it looks properly aligned in 4.2.

Comment: Strange.. I tried on another machine with `GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12.6.0)`, and it still does not align :(.

Comment: And on the other hand, it does align correctly on `GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`. Can it really be macOS vs Linux issue? Can't actually believe it :).

Comment: My 4.1-vs-4.2 test was on macOS. (Hm, actually, in Docker.) Alignment is fine in `bash` 3.2 and 4.4 when run directly in macOS.

Comment: Well, it doesn't for me: https://pastebin.com/uT72mbf8 May it not be the shell version then?

Comment: Note that `sh` is a link to `/bin/bash`, and in general `bash` can behave differently depending on whether it was invoked as `sh` or `bash`. Also, `sh` is going to be your system-default `bash` 3.2, while `bash` is your locally installed 4.4. (None of this is terribly relevant, though, since I don't seen any difference in behavior when I try your script with `sh`.)

Comment: Damn, you are absolutely right! It works now OK, thanks for your patience :)

Comment: Side note: why do you quote with `$''`? This enables ANSI-C quoting, but you're not using any escapes. You should be able to just use `''` instead.